# for(auto e : xxx) conflict with constructor

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I defined a class "eventZone" which is used in my class "configuration"

`class configuration { ... QMap<QString, eventZone> zones ... }`

Until rescently I succesfully used a for loop like saw

```
for(eventZone evz : config.zone.values()) { ... }
```

However this doesnt work since I implemented a copy constructor for eventZone (needed to serialize it and be able to save configurations)

The error I get is

```
/home/.../zonedisplay.cpp:43: erreur : no matching function for call to 'eventZone::eventZone(eventZone&)'
```

My new constructor has type :

```
explicit eventZone(const eventZone &cpy);
```

How to make those two coexist ?

Comment: I suspect the problem is the use of explicit, which in this context seems unnecessary anyway.

Comment: Are you aware that you can use `for (const EventZone& e : config.zone.values ())`, or even `for (const auto& e : config.zone.values ())` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to put `explicit` here. `explicit`'s job is to prevent implicit *conversions*, but you don't convert - you just copy. Remove it. It's only needed for single-argument constructors that have parameters of a *different* type than the class type itself.

Anyways, the usual idiom in C++ is to take references (unless you explicitly need copies), and that applies to the range-based for-loop too:

```
for(auto const& e : config.zone.values())
  // do whatever with 'e'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove explicit from copy constructors.  Or you can pass your auto value by reference...

for (auto &value : container) ...